# Preview of AutoCAD files within windows explorer

Tags: autocad

I have AutoCAD 2004 and Mechanical 2004 installed on my computer. We have an SVN setup where we have all our files located. The problem is that when i open a specific folder where it have couple hundreds files in it the explorer.exe process jump from about 45 meg ram to 2.8 gig in less than a second and explorer.exe crashes I doesn't always happen but i would say it can happen a good 15-20 times in a row and i need to restart the explorer.exe process by hand each time and eventually it works. It happen on every big folder where there are preview of the files.

My question is : What is the DLL that is responsible for generating these preview ? A collegue of mine apparently unregistered that DLL 8-9 years ago and unfortunately don't remember it.

AutoCAD are apparently unable to help me as they don't support our 2004 version of AutoCAD.

I found on the internet a solution to open the file and change a variable setting and save back the files but the only people that can open this folder anymore don't have time to go through all these huge folder where there might be 200 to 700 individual files. it would be too much work for what it's worth for them but i need to browse this folder.

Comment: Why don't you just disable preview pane?

Comment: where is that options ? the only resembling option i know is in the folder view option and its the checkbox `Show preview handlers in preview pane` and i already disabled that a long time ago.